# Is there a way to obtain temporary root (until next boot) on a locked HTC device without S-OFF?

Tags: rooting, root-access, htc-droid-dna, s-off

Let's say I want to run some app requiring root access on my HTC Droid DNA (2.06 stock firmware, 4.1 Android, NOT broken, meaning it's S-ON).

My (somewhat naive) understanding of S-ON/S-OFF is that it write-protects the ROM, and thus makes writing anything into it impossible (such as whatever changes are needed to install root that persists from boot to boot).

The question is, **is there a way to obtain *temporary* root without breaking S-ON**, such that it only persists till next boot? (with the understanding that any changes to filesystem made by the need-root application that would have been saved into protected parts of the filesystem would ALSO be lost after reboot).

P.S. Please note that the question is about technical detail about rooting - asking me to clarify which app I need to run to help me do the same task without rooting is entirely off-topic.

Comment: There used to be an app on the playstore called "System RW" that does exactly this. It needs root but it works on S-ON devices and makes `/system` writeable until reboot - The changes persisted though. It was made for HTC devices and I used it around 5 years ago. It apparently got deleted from playstore a long time ago though as I was unable to find it again ~2 years ago. I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet, maybe you have more luck. This does need root, but on my HTC I never needed S-OFF to get (permanent) root.